# How to implement something like cron jobs on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, recurring-billing

I'm developing an app in Rails 4 and not sure about how to implement a certain feature: basically I need to implement some sort of  cron job. For instance, let's say I create an invoice in my app. I need the app to check the invoice due date and send a reminder to the customer that the invoice hasn't been paid. I want to achieve this without any input from the user.

How can I achieve this?

I've been thinking about this and thought about use a tool like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) which would check the db every so often.

But is there another way to do it? Something more efficient?

Thanks

**EDIT: Inefficiencies I'm trying to avoid:**

The way I envisaged this could work is:

- An invoice is created. A due date is selected. This date is automatically added to a collection (I'm using Mongoid, but could be same as table)
- Every day whenever (the [gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)) or a cron job will fire up a script/method/function that will check the aforementioned collection for entries. If finds entries with due dates within a certain time-range (due within 3 days for instance) would fire up another script/method to notify the customer that invoice is almost due.

My concern is if there are thousands of invoices, it might be quite resource intensive to check all the entries and check whether they're within a specific time range. So, is there a better solution?

Comment: You're going to have to use CRON because it's an OS-level implementation. CRON just fires a script, in your case a Ruby script

Comment: Look for `whenever` gem. If you are using sidekiq, you can use `sidekiq-scheduler`

Comment: :) The whenever gem linked in the question?

Comment: About running Rails code against cron see http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/cron-jobs-and-rails

Comment: It would be interesting, and helpful in terms of answers, to know what inefficiencies with CRON/whenever you're trying to avoid? The main one is often the potential need to fire up a whole rails environment to do something simple but there may be other things you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to cron you could use this gem for the delayed job:

https://github.com/amitree/delayed_job_recurring

Sidekiq has also periodic jobs(although it is only present in sidekiq pro):

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Periodic-Jobs

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying on Heroku, you can use the [Heroku scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler). I have used it for a variety of tasks like backups, analytics, counts, etc.

For rails applications, you can create a rake task to to run a specific command and then use the scheduler to run the rake task periodically.

Comment: I'm not using Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

**I defined the job as an normal controller action** and set a route to it. 
With `render json: @records` I return the list of the updated records.
(Additionally I had to avoid the normally necessary login by changing the before filter inside my application_controller.rb).

Than I could test it in the browser.

I tried a `wget` (or curl) query to the defined route
and placed it in the user crontab (`crontab -e`)

I choose this solution, because I didn't wanted to use additional gems or start a rails runner task, which is so slow at startup and consumes a lot of memory.